Use Azure DevOps and GitHub APIs to migrate permissions from Azure DevOps to GitHub
How to use Azure DevOps and GitHub APIs to migrate permissions from Azure DevOps to GitHub?

From Azure DevOps side, we can use the Permissions Report related REST API to get the permissions of the repos.
Then I checked the GitHub REST API endpoints for repositories, however there is no REST API about managing permissions.
By the way, according to the Overview of a migration from Azure DevOps to GitHub Enterprise Cloud, it mentions

Because permissions work differently in GitHub than in ADO, GitHub Enterprise Importer does not attempt to migrate repository permissions from ADO.
If you used the ADO2GH CLI, GitHub Enterprise Importer will create two teams in GitHub for each team project in ADO. Each team is granted a different level of access to all repositories that originated from the team project.
To give access to migrated repositories, you can add people to these teams. You can do this manually on GitHub, or if you chose to link the teams to Azure Active Directory (AAD) groups during your migration, by managing group membership in AAD.
If you aren't using the ADO2GH CLI, or if you require a permissions configuration that is more advanced than this default, configure permissions for your migrated repositories. You can modify the migration script to suit your needs, or you can manually configure permissions after your migration.


according to this suggestion how to configure the migration script to add permissions for users in GitHub for the repos migrated to GitHub from ADO.

From the document, to generate a migration script, run the gh ado2gh generate-script command. As to how to modify the migration script, it is not documented, and maybe you can create a discuss to ask the issue here.

Any other suggestions on how to map user permissions in GitHub when migrating DevOps repos to GitHub?

In fact, Azure DevOps and GitHub are two different products. Currently, there is no API tool that can be used directly to manage the permissions between them.
